# Remove event listener after resizing to smaller screen

Tags: javascript

I only want the event listener for scrolling to be activated when the screen size is larger than 1264 pixels.

The event listener is activated when my content size starts off larger than 1264 pixels and it does not activate when the content size starts off smaller than 1264 pixels. However, when I resize from a content size greater than 1264 pixels to a content size smaller than 1264 pixels, the event listener is still activated after the resizing. I want the event listener to be turned off after I resize to smaller content size and the class sticky to be removed.

```js
function checkWindowSize() {
    ${window.innerWidth};
    if(window.innerWidth > 1264) {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            var header = document.querySelector("header"); 
            header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 0);
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Smaller");
        window.removeEventListener("scroll");
        var header = document.querySelector("header"); 
        header.classList.remove('sticky');        
    }
}

window.onresize = checkWindowSize;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `eventListener`'s function global, and give it a name. Then, you can use that name, to add and remove `eventListener`.

```js
function checkWindowSize() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 1264) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", resize);
  } else {
    alert("Smaller");
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", resize);
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
}

window.onresize = checkWindowSize;

function resize() {
  var header = document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 0);
}
```

```html
<header> HEADER </header>
```